# How to know if simple product is associated with a grouped product?

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, simple-product, grouped-products, associated-products

Excuse me for my english.

I want to know if there are a possibility to know on backend  if a simple product have associated with a grouped product. Also if there is an option to know how many grouped products have this simple product associated and their ID's.

All this questions are related with admin Panels magento panel admin. It is possible to make it with catalog grid with filters and attributes.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out of the box that will do that.  It is possible to create a custom page that can produce that information just like any other adminhtml grid.  If its built properly you can sort columns, search, export the results.